# if structs and classes are identical in C++, why do developers mix and match them?

Tags: c++, class, struct

Why not just use one or the other?

Is there a convention that applies to class vs struct?

Comment: It's a war of ideology. I'm with `struct`. death to the `class`ists!

Comment: They are not identical, please read the link I posted.

Comment: @Richard Not that much ideology, but what comes up with writing less code regarding the actual requirements.

Comment: They differ in the default access specification they use. It's mostly a question of taste. From my *personal* experience, it seems `class` is preferred except when writing very light weight types, for metaprogramming or when writing POD types.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I have *never* perceived this as a "war"...